# MVC TempData doesn't save in async method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, async-await

can't figure it out:
Have this.(I've deleted most code to simplify reading)

```
  [HttpPost]
    public  ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {

        Change();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");            
    }

public ActionResult Index()
    {

        return View();
    }
 private async void Change()
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
            {                    
                try
                {                       
                    TempData["Text"] = "Text 1";

                }
                catch 
                {
                    TempData["Text"] = "Text 2";
                }

            });
```

View 
@TempData["Text"]

I need to change it, but it doesn't change. Need some help or maybe other ways to do it(I just need to change text depending on conditions in "Change" func and show it to the user).
Thanks!

Comment: What version of ASP.NET MVC are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`async void` means that the method is `fire-and-forget`. The controller will not wait for it to finish so by the time you try to set `TempData`, the response has already been sent back to the client.

Assuming you are using ASP.NET MVC 4 or later, you will have to change the signature of `Change` to `async Task` and make your action asynchronous:

```
[HttpPost]
public  async Task<ActionResult> UploadAsync(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{

    await Change();

    return RedirectToAction("Index");            
}

private async Task Change()
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
        {                    
            try
            {                       
                TempData["Text"] = "Text 1";

            }
            catch 
            {
                TempData["Text"] = "Text 2";
            }
        });
}
```

Actually, there is no reason to use `async/await` in `Change` if it simply calls Task.Run. You can write:

```
private Task Change()
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
        {                    
            try
            {                       
                TempData["Text"] = "Text 1";

            }
            catch 
            {
                TempData["Text"] = "Text 2";
            }

        });
}
```

You can find a full tutorial on using asynchronous methods [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4)